# Tab to next visible column in QTableView

Tags: c++, qt

I have a custom `QTableView` and `QAbstractTableModel`. My `QTableView` hides some of the columns from the `QAbstractTableModel` as they aren't needed.

When I hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>, I would like to select the next available (editable) column. My current implementation is to grab the next index from the `QAbstractTableModel`, but this index includes columns that are hidden. (So when hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd> it may be a couple presses before you see the "next" column selected.)

How can I tell <kbd>Tab</kbd> to jump to the next visible column?

The language is C++. Below is the code within my `QTableView`:

```
void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent* event)
{
    if((event->modifiers() == Qt::KeyboardModifier::NoModifier) && (event->key() == Qt::Key::Key_Tab))
    {
        this->moveToNextCell();
    }
    else
    {
        this->QTableView::keyPressEvent(event);
    }
}

void moveToNextCell()
{
    const QModelIndex index = this->currentIndex();
    int nextColumn = index.column() + 1;

    if(index.column() <= lastEditableCol)
    {       
        this->setCurrentIndex(model->index(index.row(), nextColumn));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not elegant, but I've solved the problem by using `isColumnHidden()` from `QTableView`. I just iterate through the columns until I find one that isn't hidden.

```
for(int i = nextColumn; i <= numOfColumns && nextColumn <= numOfColumns; i++)
{
    if(this->isColumnHidden(nextColumn) == true)
    {
        nextColumn += 1;
    }
    else
    {
        i = numOfCol + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Be aware of void QHeaderView::setSectionsMovable(bool movable)